# through vs. from vs. nothing at all?

Tags: prepositions

I've been thinking so hard over this for a good 15 minutes. Would like to know which makes sense?

...the Member State which the asylum seeker first enters European Union (EU) is responsible for processing the asylum claim.

...the Member State which the asylum seeker first enters European Union (EU) through is responsible for processing the asylum claim.

... the Member State which the asylum seeker first enters European Union (EU) from is responsible for…

Thanks a lot!

Comment: through which...enters _the_ EU

Comment: OR the Member State the AS first enters in the EU. Both work. This one avoids the which.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first deconstruct your sentence into two independent clauses and worry later about combining them by subordination.

> The Member State is responsible for processing the asylum claim.
>
> The asylum seeker enters the European Union ________ a Member State.

The preposition *from* doesn't work because, while one might enter the EU *from* a non-member state like Turkey or Morocco, once an asylum seeker has arrived in a member state, they are already in the EU. One cannot enter a place where one already is.

Instead, one enters the EU *through* a member state, say Italy or Poland, even if the ultimate goal is France or Germany. This yields:

> The asylum seeker enters the European Union through a Member State.

Subordinating this sentence to the first as a relative clause modifying the noun phrase *the Member State* yields:

> The Member State through which an asylum seeker enters the European Union is responsible for processing the asylum claim.

There is no need for stranding the preposition in the construction *which the asylum seeker enters the EU through*. This is fine for informal conversation or writing with different vocabulary and a lower register but not for formal writing.

Answer (score -1):

The first two are equivalent and appropriate.

The third seems to imply that the individual comes originally from the EU which they do not by definition. It is meant to mean "The EU country From which they enter the other countries is responsible...". It could pass but the first two are better.